# Генерация всех пилообразных кортежей длины n над множеством {0, 1}

Tags: c++, алгоритм, комбинаторика

У меня есть множество A={0, 1}.

Как мне сгенерировать все пилообразные кортежи длины n над множеством А, то есть такие кортежи, у которых элементы на чётных позициях не меньшие, чем элементы на соседних с ними нечётных позициях?

P.S: Сначала думал просто сгенрировать все кортежи длины n, а потом выбрать те, которые удовлетворяют условию. Но такой подход очень не эффективен.

P.P.S: Рекурсией пользоваться нельзя.

Comment: и чем вам рекурсия мешает? замените её на стек =). Приведите пример ваших попыток, что именно не получилось. Решение здесь не особо сложное из-за всего двух значений 0/1. Я бы сделал так, сделал генарицию всех чётных позиций. (легко через обычныю битовую маску кстати) потом прошёлся бы и расставил 0 в соседних с 0 элементами. Потом 2 генерация 0/1 на то что осталось. Опять бит маска...

Answer (score 1):

Cначала сгенерируй массив всех возможных четных позиций
потом генерируй массив соответствующих нечетных позиций
После этого пройдешь циклом и склешь готовые кортежи

Comment: Проблема заключается в том, что я не знаю, как реализовать заполнение массива соответствующих нечётных позиций. К примеру, если первые два элемента массива чётных позиций являются единицами, понятно, что в массиве нечётных позиций нужно будет сгенерить 1 и 0, и каждый из этих вариантов запомнить и идти дальше. Но я не знаю, как это сделать.

Comment: используйте 2-мерный массив размерности 2^L на 2